# Woocommerce increment and decrement buttons are not aligning

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

The increment button on my product and cart Woocommerce pages is suddenly not in line with the rest of the rectangle anymore.

[image: Here is what it looks like]

Is there any custom CSS I can add to rectify this?

[Here](http://bugbags.co.za/product/surfboard-bag/) is a link to the website.

Comment: that is already custom CSS (and JS) that shows +/- buttons. check if it uses flex and fix it with align-items

Comment: When I inspect the CSS, I see display is set to 'inline-block'. There is no mention of flex.

Comment: it can be still present, if not, vertical-align can help, also check height, margins, paddings in inspector, Box Model should be helpful

Comment: @bolshevik You should provide **a live link to your web site**, editing your question… Without it, this question is just not solvable and nobody will be able to help you…

Comment: Thanks, I have now done so.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove:

```
padding-top: 35px;
```

from:

```
body[data-form-style="minimal"] .minimal-form-input
```

it fixes it.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the problem.